# Grid does not work for values greater than 30x30

Tags: c, raylib

I am trying to make Conway's Game of Life using C and raylib.  In this program, I am facing issues to generate a grid greater than 30 such as 40x40 or 100x100.
The program works fine for 30x30, but as soon as I change the value the program breaks.
Only half the grid is generated and half the screen is blank.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"

int main()
{   
    int up, down, left, right;
    int life;
    int k, i, j;
    int COLS = 30;
    int ROWS = 30;
    int spaceC = 0;
    int mouseC = 0;
    int screenWidth = 600;
    int screenHeight = 600;
    int cellWidth = screenWidth / ROWS;
    int cellHeight = screenHeight / COLS;
    int mat[ROWS][COLS];
    int buffer[ROWS][COLS];

    SetTargetFPS(60);
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "try render");
//default
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                if (mat[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    DrawRectangleLines(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, WHITE);
                }
                else
                {
                    DrawRectangle(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, BLACK);
                }
                DrawRectangleLines(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, GRAY);
            }
        }

        if (IsMouseButtonPressed(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
        {
            Vector2 mPos = GetMousePosition();
            int x = mPos.x / cellWidth;
            int y = mPos.y / cellHeight;
            if (x >= 0 && x < ROWS && y >= 0 && y < COLS)
            {
                if (mat[x][y] != 1)
                {
                    mouseC = 1;
                    mat[x][y] = 1;
                }
                else if (mouseC == 1 && mat[x][y] == 1) {
                    mouseC=0;
                    mat[x][y] = 0;
                }           
            }
        }

        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE))
        {
            spaceC++;
        }
        if (spaceC % 2 != 0)
        {
            SetTargetFPS(4);
            for (k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                    {
                        right = (j + 1) % COLS;
                        left = ((j - 1) + COLS) % COLS;
                        up = ((i - 1) + ROWS) % ROWS;
                        down = (i + 1) % ROWS;

                        life = mat[down][j] + mat[i][left] + mat[up][left] + mat[up][j] + mat[up][right] + mat[i][right] + mat[down][right] + mat[down][left];

                        if (mat[i][j] == 1 && (life < 2 || life > 3))
                        {
                            buffer[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                        else if (mat[i][j] == 1 && (life == 2 || life == 3))
                        {
                            buffer[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if (mat[i][j] == 0 && life == 3)
                        {
                            buffer[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer[i][j] = mat[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                    {
                        mat[i][j] = buffer[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, The issue you are facing is that you’re setting the screen width and screen height to 600, and then dividing these by ROWS and COLS to get the cell width and cell height. This works fine when ROWS and COLS are 30 because 600 divided by 30 is a whole number 20. However, when you increase ROWS and COLS to 40 or 100, 600 is not divisible. To solve this -  if you want a 40x40 grid, you can try to set screen width and screen height to 800 (since 800 is a multiple of 40). Same, for a 100x100 grid, you could set screen width and screen height to 1000.
Please try. Thanks

Comment: @HarishDalmia: 15x40 = 600; 6 x 100 = 600.  It isn't clear whether your argument holds up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir , I had tried setting to 800 it still broke the grid

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious but the dependency on raylib limits who can help you (reproduce the issue).

Comment: Prefer symbolic constants to variables (#define or enum).

Comment: Prefer to minimize scope of variables.

Comment: Consider introducing some functions.  The first loop initializes `mat` to 0 and the last one copies `buffer` to `mat`.

Comment: `i-1` and `j-1` when loop starts at `i=0` and `j=0` tingles my spider sense.  Also signed underflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: `if(mat[x][y]!=1) { ...} else if(mouseC==1&&mat[x][y]==1){` is either a bug or you can leave out `mat[x][y]==1`.  Also consider adding some space around your operators as the whole expression otherwise blur together (readability).

Comment: If you only care if `spaceC` is odd or event consider using `spaceC = (spaceC + 1) % 2`  instead of `spaceC++` which may overflow.  Or use a unsigned type which is well defined for overflow.

Comment: Consider if `r` and `c` is clearer index names than `i` and `j`.

Comment: `i-1` and `j-1` when loop starts at `i=0` and `j=0` tingles my spider sense when subsequently used for array indices.

Comment: `buffer` and `mat` is each 1.4 MB.  What's the stack size on your platform?  Consider using heap (i.e. `malloc`) instead of vla.

Comment: If you only need to store values 0 and 1 in `mat` and `buffer` consider using an `unsigned char` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the display is broken is you do not redisplay between the calls `BeginDrawing(); ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);` and `EndDrawing();`.

Note also these remarks:

- there is still a confusion between rows and columns: you set `mat[x][y]` in the cell update code instead of `mat[y][x]`, and you use the wrong variables in the display code: it should be `j * cellWidth, i * cellHeight` instead of `i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight`
- using `row` and `col` as index variables would make the code more readable and less error prone.
- there is no need for `DrawRectangleLines(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, WHITE);` in the display code if the matrix cell is not set because the background has been cleared.
- you can use the xor operator to simplify the mouse toggle code:

  ```
    mat[row][col] ^= 1;
  ```
- the game logic can also be simplified:

  ```
    if (mat[i][j] == 1) {
        buffer[i][j] = (life == 2 || life == 3);
    } else {
        buffer[i][j] = (life == 3);
    }
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"

int main(void)
{
    int COLS = 40;
    int ROWS = 40;
    int spaceC = 0;
    int mouseC = 0;
    int screenWidth = 600;
    int screenHeight = 600;
    int cellWidth = screenWidth / COLS;
    int cellHeight = screenHeight / ROWS;
    int fps = 60;
    int mat[ROWS][COLS];
    int buffer[ROWS][COLS];

    SetTargetFPS(fps);
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "try render");

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        if (IsMouseButtonPressed(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT)) {
            Vector2 mPos = GetMousePosition();
            int col = (int)mPos.x / cellWidth;
            int row = (int)mPos.y / cellHeight;
            if (row >= 0 && row < ROWS && col >= 0 && col < COLS) {
                mat[row][col] ^= 1;
            }
        }

        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE)) {
            spaceC++;
        }
        if (spaceC % 2 != 0) {
            if (fps != 8) {
                SetTargetFPS(fps = 8);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                        int up = (i - 1 + ROWS) % ROWS;
                        int down = (i + 1) % ROWS;
                        int right = (j + 1) % COLS;
                        int left = (j - 1 + COLS) % COLS;
                        int life = mat[up][left] + mat[up][j] + mat[up][right] +
                            mat[i][left] + mat[i][right] +
                            mat[down][j] + mat[down][left] + mat[down][right];

                        if (mat[i][j] == 1) {
                            buffer[i][j] = (life == 2 || life == 3);
                        } else {
                            buffer[i][j] = (life == 3);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                        mat[i][j] = buffer[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                if (mat[row][col] != 0) {
                    DrawRectangle(col * cellWidth, row * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, BLACK);
                }
                DrawRectangleLines(col * cellWidth, row * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, GRAY);
            }
        }
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello sir thank you, but i have a little confusion here
```c
 if (mat[i][j] == 1) {
      buffer[i][j] = (life == 2 || life == 3);
  } else {
      buffer[i][j] = (life == 3);
  }
```
when mat[i][j] is 1 then buffter is assigned what value i didnot understood this part
```c
buffer[i][j] = (life == 2 || life == 3);
```

Comment: @IllDimension101: `(life == 2 || life == 3)` is a boolean expression that evaluates to `1` if true and `0` if false, as all boolean expressions in C.

Comment: @IllDimension101: for clarity, you could write a redundant expression `(life == 2 || life == 3) ? 1 : 0`